# OBB collision detection detecting translation vector incorrectly

Tags: c#, opengl, collision-detection, opentk, bounding-box

**EDIT: Fixed thanks to stackoverflow.com**
*Some cases were missing in CalculateOverlap(). Added them for you to see.*

---

I have a C# Hitbox class (see code below, especially the **CollisionTest()** method) that uses SAT for detecting collisions between two OBBs. This works perfectly well for the following case...

[image: Working collision detection example]

... but it fails completely in the following case:

[image]

The calculated minimum-translation-vector is way too high, resulting in the object jumping up instead of just adjusting to the colliding object.

What do I need to do in order to improve my algorithm? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
using OpenTK;

namespace KWEngine2.Collision3D
{
    public class Hitbox
    {
        private static Vector3[] STATICVERTICES = new Vector3[]
        { 
            new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f),
            new Vector3(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f),
            new Vector3(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),

            new Vector3(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f)
        };

        private static Vector3[] STATICNORMALS = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 0, 1)
        };

        private static Vector3 STATICCENTER = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // Holds the currently transformed vertices of the bounding box
        private Vector3[] _vertices = new Vector3[8];

        // Holds the currently transformed surface normals of the bounding box
        private Vector3[] _normals = new Vector3[3];

        // Holds the currently transformed center point of the bounding box
        private Vector3 _center = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


        private static Matrix4 CreateModelMatrix(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
        {
            // Create the basic 4x4 rotation matrix:
            Matrix4 m = Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation);

            // Multiply the first three rows by the scale to add the given scale:
            m.Row0 *= scale.X;
            m.Row1 *= scale.Y;
            m.Row2 *= scale.Z;

            // Replace the lowest row with the position data:
            m.Row3.X = position.X;
            m.Row3.Y = position.Y;
            m.Row3.Z = position.Z;
            m.Row3.W = 1.0f;

            return m;
        }


        public Hitbox()
        {
            Update(Vector3.Zero, Quaternion.Identity, Vector3.One);
        }

        public Hitbox(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
        {
            Update(position, rotation, scale);
        }

        public void Update(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
        {
            Matrix4 modelMatrix = CreateModelMatrix(position, rotation, scale);

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (i < 3)
                {
                    Vector3.TransformNormal(ref STATICNORMALS[i], ref modelMatrix, out _normals[i]);
                }
                // transform the corner points by multiplying them by the model matrix:
                Vector3.TransformPosition(ref STATICVERTICES[i], ref modelMatrix, out _vertices[i]);
            }
            // transform the center point by multiplying it by the model matrix:
            Vector3.TransformPosition(ref STATICCENTER, ref modelMatrix, out _center);
        }

        public static bool CollisionTest(Hitbox a, Hitbox b, out Vector3 MTV)
        {

            float mtvDistance = float.MaxValue;
            float mtvDirection = 1;
            MTV = Vector3.Zero;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                bool error;
                float shape1Min, shape1Max, shape2Min, shape2Max;
                SatTest(ref a._normals[i], ref a._vertices, out shape1Min, out shape1Max);
                SatTest(ref a._normals[i], ref b._vertices, out shape2Min, out shape2Max);
                if (!Overlaps(shape1Min, shape1Max, shape2Min, shape2Max))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    CalculateOverlap(ref a._normals[i], ref shape1Min, ref shape1Max, ref shape2Min, ref shape2Max,
                        out error, ref mtvDistance, ref MTV, ref mtvDirection, ref a._center, ref b._center);
                    if (error)
                        return false;
                }


                SatTest(ref b._normals[i], ref a._vertices, out shape1Min, out shape1Max);
                SatTest(ref b._normals[i], ref b._vertices, out shape2Min, out shape2Max);
                if (!Overlaps(shape1Min, shape1Max, shape2Min, shape2Max))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    CalculateOverlap(ref b._normals[i], ref shape1Min, ref shape1Max, ref shape2Min, ref shape2Max,
                        out error, ref mtvDistance, ref MTV, ref mtvDirection, ref a._center, ref b._center);
                    if (error)
                        return false;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        private static void SatTest(ref Vector3 axisToTest, ref Vector3[] points, out float minAlong, out float maxAlong)
        {
            minAlong = float.MaxValue;
            maxAlong = float.MinValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                float dotVal = Vector3.Dot(points[i], axisToTest);
                if (dotVal < minAlong) minAlong = dotVal;
                if (dotVal > maxAlong) maxAlong = dotVal;
            }
        }

        private static bool Overlaps(float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2)
        {
            return IsBetweenOrdered(min2, min1, max1) || IsBetweenOrdered(min1, min2, max2);
        }

        private static bool IsBetweenOrdered(float val, float lowerBound, float upperBound)
        {
            return lowerBound <= val && val <= upperBound;
        }

        private static void CalculateOverlap(ref Vector3 axis, ref float shape1Min, ref float shape1Max, ref float shape2Min, ref float shape2Max,
            out bool error, ref float mtvDistance, ref Vector3 mtv, ref float mtvDirection, ref Vector3 posA, ref Vector3 posB)
        {
            // THIS PART IS NEW!
            float intersectionDepthScaled;
            if (shape1Min < shape2Min)
            {
                if (shape1Max > shape2Max)
                {
                    float diff1 = shape1Max - shape2Max;
                    float diff2 = shape2Min - shape1Min;
                    if(diff1 > diff2)
                    {
                        intersectionDepthScaled = shape2Max - shape1Min;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intersectionDepthScaled = shape2Min - shape1Max;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    intersectionDepthScaled = shape1Max - shape2Min; // default
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if(shape1Max < shape2Max)
                {
                    float diff1 = shape2Max - shape1Max;
                    float diff2 = shape1Min - shape2Min;
                    if (diff1 > diff2)
                    {
                        intersectionDepthScaled = shape1Max - shape2Min;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intersectionDepthScaled = shape1Min - shape2Max;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    intersectionDepthScaled = shape1Min - shape2Max; // default
                }

            }
            // END OF NEW PART

            float axisLengthSquared = Vector3.Dot(axis, axis);
            if (axisLengthSquared < 1.0e-8f)
            {
                error = true;
                return;
            }
            float intersectionDepthSquared = (intersectionDepthScaled * intersectionDepthScaled) / axisLengthSquared;

            error = false;

            if (intersectionDepthSquared < mtvDistance || mtvDistance < 0)
            {
                mtvDistance = intersectionDepthSquared;
                mtv = axis * (intersectionDepthScaled / axisLengthSquared);
                float notSameDirection = Vector3.Dot(posA - posB, mtv);
                mtvDirection = notSameDirection < 0 ? -1.0f : 1.0f;
                mtv = mtv * mtvDirection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that somewhere (did not find out where) you check if lower bound of A is inside B.

You missed the case in which lower Bound of A is under lower bound of B AND upper bound of A is above upper bound of B.

Comment: Hmm, but if I missed this case, the algorithm would not detect a collision at all, right? But it does, only the MTV is incorrect.

Comment: But wait, maybe in the CalculateOverlap():float intersectionDepthScaled = (shape1Min < shape2Min) ? (shape1Max - shape2Min) : (shape1Min - shape2Max);

Comment: @Emanuele please leave an answer here so I can vote it as correct. I already fixed it in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that somewhere (into CalculateOverlap) you check if lower bound of A is inside B. You missed the case in which lower Bound of A is under lower bound of B AND upper bound of A is above upper bound of B.